# How to play music using libgdx

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

I have had trouble playing music using libgdx. My code is as follows:

```
package com.me.fixGame;

import java.util.Random;


import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;


import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Scaling;
import com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task;


public class fixGame implements ApplicationListener {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture trash; 
    Texture paper;
    SpriteBatch spritebatch;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 pas;
    boolean collide;
    boolean countMe=false;
    Vector2 size;
    Vector2 size2;
    Vector2 pos;
    Rectangle bounds;
    float posSpeed=30;
    Rectangle bounds2;
    float delay = 1; // seconds
    boolean counted= false;
    int score = 3;
    //Texture Gogreen;
    String myScore;
    Texture background; 
    CharSequence str = "Lives left: 3"; // = myScore;
    CharSequence line = "Score: 0"; // = myScore;
    String myLife;
    int life=0;
    BitmapFont font;
    float x;
    float y;
    Sound sound;
    boolean collision = false;
    @Override
    public void create() {  

        //Gogreen = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gogreenNow.jpg"));
        background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));

        x= background.getWidth();
        y=background.getHeight();
        //float delaySeconds = 1;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        trash = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));
        paper = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/paper1.jpg"));
        sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/testjava.mp3"));

        position = new Vector2(100, 50);
        pos = new Vector2(54, 14);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();

        size2 = new Vector2(trash.getWidth() ,trash.getHeight() );
        //size2.y = trash.getHeight();
        //size2.x = trash.getWidth();
        size = new Vector2(paper.getWidth() ,paper.getHeight());

        bounds= new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
        bounds2= new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
    public void update(){
        bounds.set(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
        bounds2.set(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);
        float pos1=Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        //if(pos1<0)
        //  pos1=(-1)*pos1;
        position.x = position.x - 5*pos1;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        sound.play(0.5f);
        sound.dispose();    
        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){
            collision=true; 
            counted=true;
        }else{
            collision=false;
        }

        if(collision==true){

        } 
        if(pos.y<640){
            counted=false;
        } else if(pos.y > 640 && collision==false && counted==false){
            counted=true;
            score= score-1;
            myScore = "Lives left: " + score;
            str = myScore;
        }


        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){
            countMe=true;
            life= life+50;
            myLife = "Score: " + life;
            line = myLife;
        }


        if(position.x<0){
            position.x= position.x+11;
        }
        if(position.x>425){
            position.x= position.x-11;
        }


        update();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        pos.y=pos.y-posSpeed;
        //posSpeed = posSpeed+(2/3);
        if(pos.y<0){
            pos.y = 700;
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            pos.x = randomGenerator.nextInt(500);
        }
        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();


        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        if (!collision) {
            batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);

        }

        //batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);
        batch.draw(trash, position.x, position.y);
        font.setScale(3);

        font.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f);
        font.draw(batch, str, 300,900);
        font.draw(batch, line, 300, 950);
        batch.end();
        font.dispose();     
    }

     @Override  
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

My sound file I call over here:

```
 sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/testjava.mp3"));
```

And the code I use to play it is:

```
 sound.play();
 sound.dispose();
```

For some reason it does not work on my desktop and my phone. I tested the the sound file actually had some sound in it.

Comment: The problem is, that you call `play(0.5f)` in render loop, and directly after play you call `dispose()`. Call play in the create and see if it is working. And call `dispose()` inside the `dispose()` method of your `ApplicationListener`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `sound.dispose();` call right after playing the sound, since it will dispose the sound file ;)

Just put it into your game's `dispose();` method, so it will get removed after the game is done.

Also, you shouldn't call `sound.play(0.5f);` within your render-loop. Remember this function will get called about 60 times a second and you don't want to have the sound start 60 times a second.

So if it's some kind of sound effect that comes with a special event, like firing a bullet or hitting a target etc, just call `sound.play();` one time, when you are actually firing the event.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects

If you want to play background music, you should try streaming the music file. The wiki is awesome for that: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Streaming-music

Hope it helps :)